Drizzle postgres migration gives lots of type errors
I wanted to use drizzle for my project. But it seems I can't migrate as it is producing lots of type errors.
My package.json is very simple
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/node": "^20.12.12",
        "drizzle-kit": "^0.20.14",
        "tsx": "^4.10.3",
        "typescript": "^5.4.5"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
        "drizzle-orm": "^0.29.5",
        "postgres": "^3.4.4"
      },


migration file is this
import 'dotenv/config';
    import { drizzle } from 'drizzle-orm/postgres-js';
    import { migrate } from 'drizzle-orm/postgres-js/migrator';
    import postgres from 'postgres';

    const migrationClient = postgres(process.env.DATABASE_URL as string, {
      max: 1,
    });

    async function main() {
      await migrate(drizzle(migrationClient), {
        migrationsFolder: './src/drizzle/migrations',
      });

      await migrationClient.end();
    }

    main();

drizzle.config file is this
    import { defineConfig } from 'drizzle-kit';
    import type { Config } from 'drizzle-kit';

    export default defineConfig({
      schema: './src/drizzle/schema.ts',
      out: './src/drizzle/migrations',
      driver: 'pg',
      dbCredentials: {
        connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL as string,
      },
      verbose: true,
      strict: true,
    }) satisfies Config;

Schema file is this
    import { pgTable, uuid, serial, varchar } from 'drizzle-orm/pg-core';

    export const USerTable = pgTable('user', {
      id: uuid('id').primaryKey().defaultRandom().notNull(),
      name: varchar('name', { length: 255 }).notNull(),
    });

When I tried to migrate, it gives the following error
    Found 21 errors in 11 files.

    Errors  Files
         1  node_modules/drizzle-orm/mysql-core/db.d.ts:1
         1  node_modules/drizzle-orm/mysql-core/query-builders/delete.d.ts:32
         7  node_modules/drizzle-orm/mysql-core/query-builders/select.d.ts:199
         1  node_modules/drizzle-orm/mysql-core/query-builders/select.types.d.ts:130
         1  node_modules/drizzle-orm/pg-core/query-builders/query.d.ts:23
         1  node_modules/drizzle-orm/query-builders/select.types.d.ts:11
         1  node_modules/drizzle-orm/sqlite-core/columns/blob.d.ts:2
         1  node_modules/drizzle-orm/sqlite-core/query-builders/query.d.ts:25
         5  node_modules/drizzle-orm/sqlite-core/query-builders/select.d.ts:202
         1  node_modules/drizzle-orm/sqlite-core/query-builders/select.types.d.ts:122


include your schema file in the post

Your Schema looks okay. From the error logs the issue could be with drizzle-orm/* modules. Can you try updating the code in index.ts under drizzle folder
import {drizzle } from "drizzle-orm/postgres-js"
import postgres from "postgres"
import { migrate } from "drizzle-orm/postgres-js/migrator";
import * as schema from './src/drizzle/schema';


const client = postgres(process.env.DATABASE_URL ?? "")
const db = drizzle(client,{schema})

const migrationClient = postgres('postgresql://postgres:password@localhost:5432/postgres', { max: 1 });
migrate(drizzle(migrationClient),{ migrationsFolder: "./src/drizzle/migrations" })

console.log("Migrations Run SuccessFully")

export default db

And you can comment out the migration file, since above we are running migrations and initalize the db together. Once done run :-
npx prisma format
npx prisma validate
npx prisma migrate dev
npx prisma generate

Another way to overcome this would by setting "skipLibCheck": true, in tsconfig.json, but i won't recomment it since it would still be considered a hack not a solution. If you face same issue, then it would be great if you could show the where the schema's been used.

It does not work, also skipLibCheck does not change anything. Same problem.

Basically, drizzle includes the types for all the drivers it supports. The errors you see are there because you don't have those other drivers installed, so TS cannot find those type declarations
You could install those other libraries you don't need just to please the compiler, ideally "skipLibCheck": "true" should have worked, so these error get skipped.
